# How to sftp into non-AWS SFTP from rails app on ec2 instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been working on this for a while now. I currently have a rails application on an AWS Ec2 instance. I have set up sidekiq/redis and have been deploying with capistrano. I am working to SFTP into a NON-AWS sftp server. I have added the gem 'net-sftp' and bundle installed locally and then deployed. Worker runs when expected.

Currently when running worker locally (starting redis,sidekiq,rails c run worker) everything runs as expected with the following code:

```
Net::SFTP.start(sftp_host, sftp_user, :password => sftp_pass) do |sftp|
        sftp.download!("/import/", "storage/", :recursive => true)
end
```

Yet on my AWS EC2 Rails application I get the following error:
`"error_message":"Net::SFTP::StatusException opendir /import/ (2, \"no such file\")"...`

I can SSH directly into EC2 instance (Ubuntu) and connect to sftp server directly from command line and see directory and files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you pass host/user/password to the worker? My first guess would be that something is going wrong there. You can try to reproduce it from prod Rails console by calling `MyJob.perform_sync(args)`

Comment: I am using ENV[“creds”].
The first error I received was for not being able to use Rails.credentials.dig but then changed to ENV and seemed to connect with no problem. I have tested running the job directly from the rails console with Job. perform_sync() and works perfectly.

Comment: Would you say the problem was a typo/infra then?

Comment: I have looked into it more and changed back to Rails.application.credentails.dig.. but now missing master key . I have added the master.key from the rails application to the AWS EC2 in shared/config but it is still not finding the master key. Rather receiving the error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when looking up rails encrypted credentials.

Comment: I have just figured it out! I just needed to add to my linked_files in my deploy.rb for capistrano 'config/master.key'. Your responses helped me dig further into the variables being passed in so THANK YOU!!